# 娘、本を投げてパパに渡した事があって怒ったんです。 Can anyone explain what is going on in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

I am at a loss, as this just makes no sense to me. I might have already forgotten some nuance of the language, but for an hour I tried to translate this to something that makes sense, and was not able to. This is a sentence, with no other context, so that's of no help either. Could also be that there are typos.

娘、本を投げてパパに渡した事があって怒ったんです。

Who does what in this sentence, who is angry, who throws the book and just what is going on here?

Comment: This sentence is understandable but is poorly-written. This is not from a good textbook, right? I'm curious how you encountered such a sentence without context. And why do you think there may be typos? Was this correctly copied from the source?

Comment: This was a test question for a translation, so I am not sure where it comes from. As it is coming from China, I am suspecting that maybe something has been altered or just poorly translated.

Comment: Oh, I think I have seen Chinese-made JLPT exercise with quite a few errors somewhere on the net. If that's what you are using, I recommend using a decent textbook...

Comment: I got it. Shame I didn't think of it right from the start. This is a literal translation from Chinese, so hence, the not making sense part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly-written sentence (see the comments), but the most natural interpretation is:

> 娘**が**本を投げてパパに渡した事があって、(私は)怒ったんです。
> My daughter once passed a book to her father by throwing it, which made me mad.

- The speaker's daughter threw the book to the speaker's daughter's father (i.e., the speaker's husband).
- The speaker ("I") scolded her daughter (saying "Don't treat books roughly!").
- As to why the speaker called her husband パパ, see: [When referring to herself, is there any pronoun other than お母さん when speaking to her children?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25947/5010)

Answer (score 0):

I reckon パパ would imply a familiar person is the subject of the sentence. So, it should be the mother of 娘.

The kids calling your parents パパ or ママ is a universal phenomena in the world.

So, the mother of the daughter should be angry due to her daughter throwing books away to the father. Other possibility regarding the subject is the relative of 娘 because they are calling パパ, but without further context it's not so natural interpretation.

娘**が**... makes the agent of throwing books clearer than 娘、... though, the sentence is understandable. I think attaching any possessive markers like うちの(i.e うちの娘、) or something makes the agent clearer.